# how to deal with symbol lookup error?

Tags: makefile, dynamic-linking, automake, dynamic-library

```
a.out call function fooA() using dlopen function to open libA.so.
fooA() is defined in libA.so  //dynamic library
fooA() call function fooB();
fooB() is defined in libB.a   //statistic library
fooB() call function fooC();
fooC() is defined in libC.so   //dynamic library
libA.so libB.a libC.so are not in the same folder.
****
```

It's ok when i compile them .But i got runtime error which is "**symbol lookup error:  libA.so: undefined symbol: fooC()**" .I dont know why . And how to solve this problem  that functions called between dynamic library and statistic library?

I am sorry . My English is poor .I don't know whether i describe  my question clearly or not.

Comment: what is an output of `ldd libA.so`? Have you linked it with `libB` and `libC`?

Answer (score 0):

Is anything in your binary bringing in libC.so? (directly or through `dlopen()` with `RTLD_GLOBAL`)? If not, that's your problem.

libA.so should be built to link to libC (and it was not).